# posting variable on securetrading.net

Tags: php, secure-gateway

I want to post variables like
street address, postal code, phone number, county , I'm not sure how could I achieve this.

https://securetrading.net/authorize/form.cgi

I used standard html post.

```
<form action="https://securetrading.net/authorize/form.cgi" method="post">

</form>
```

but not sure how to pass this.

Comment: Hi Ricky, Please email support@securetrading.com and provide us with your SecureTrading Site Reference / Username so that we can assist you with your query. Kind regards, SecureTrading Support

Comment: @SecureTrading: While we appreciate you coming here and helping our users (and you don't have enough rep for a comment), please realize that answers are supposed to be answers, not requests to email support.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic form and set its action to that specific url.

like:

```
<form action = "https://securetrading.net/authorize/form.cgi">
.....
</form>
```

Comment: what are the basic hidden input fields that needs to be added?

Comment: you can checkout the manuals or SDk provided with your account with them

Comment: @ricky I also need to find this out, it seems to be hidden deep in the secure trading website